# Views Slideshow fixed 1st slide even though its random order

Tags: views

I'm using D7.15, Views Slideshow 7.x-3.0, jQuery Cycle 2.9999.8.

The problem is that when Slideshow initially starts, even though it is set to show random order of slides (~100 nodes linking via Views), the first slide is always the same and it is shown in a bit glitched way - it does not works as a link, it is shown for shorter amount of seconds and in general does look like it is shown while all the rest of slideshow is loading. Starting from the second slide the order is random and it works perfectly. It can also be recreated in case of page refresh - if you refresh the page in any browser you may get the same result no matter of what browser you use. You can check it here http://www.scanorama.lt (the main slider part).

I have searched for this issue registered at Drupal issue queue, but it looks like that there is none.

Any ideas, what could be the reason for such glitch?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if your slides are always appearing in the same order in the source code.

Are you sure that the order in your view is set to random?

i.e
SORT CRITERIA,
Global: Random (asc)

nothing else.

Also I would really recommend not having that many nodes in your slideshow as It creates an insane amount of html markup which is not great for a number of reasons and performance will really take a hit. 5 or less slides would be ideal I would say about 10 should be an absolute maximum.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! The problem is that I need that kind of structure, as it is a film festival and slider randomly shows teasers through which visitor can get into description of the movie. That's the request of the client. But about the random order - it is randomized and this first slide (if you've looked at it, you saw slide with a man with white face) - is always the same. I actually cannot understand why it happens.

Comment: Actually I have checked and there was no SORT CRITERIA,Global:Random (asc), but there is randomizing option in Views Slideshow itself. But I've tried to turn this option on and the only thing that happened - the first slide has changed! :)

Comment: So It now works as you expected? The first slide probably loads before jQuery cycle has a chance to kick in (as it's javascript) especially as you have so many slides loading before the document is ready.

Comment: Well, yes, the randomization works now good, but how to solve that loading problem? Maybe I could place some priority on jQuery Cycle loading?

Comment: You have a different slide loading first now but they all still appear in the same order each time. Did you save the sort by random in the view? As for making jQuery Cycle load earlier it is not really something I have ever tried to do. I would assume that it wouldn't work though as cycle most likely needs all of the slides to be loaded before it starts.

Comment: I presume that view randomizes list and displays it but the randomized list will remain the same until the page is refreshed. If I go to another page, then come back, the random order of the slides is different. As for jQuery preloding priority - i have no clue what to do, it is really annoying to see some elements jumping into their places while all the rest of stuff is loading. Maybe it is possible to put priority for all the module? Well, that's what I have no experience in at all...

Comment: This is why you shouldn't load 100 nodes simultaneously into a slideshow. What may work is using views infinite scroll http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll set a pager with like 5 items and use the infinite scroller. This should load 5 items at a time using ajax so you won't have to wait for 100 to load before the slideshow starts ( but should achieve the same effect ).

Comment: This sounds very interesting. I don't understand how to implement it yet, but will give it a try! :)

Comment: It looks like it doesn't change anything - I've installed it, configured it to load 5 nodes at a time, but the first slide loads in a same wicked manner, maybe I'm doing something wrong, or maybe the reason for wickedness is different. Anyway, it looks like a good stuff, this infinite scroll.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6356/discussion-between-james-and-benasplentas)